# Merging Git branches locally vs merging in remote repository?

Tags: git

Scenario 1:

- I have 'master' branch in both local and remote repositories
- I create a 'feature-1' branch and make few commits in it.
- Merge 'feature-1' branch in to 'master' branch
- push changes to remote 'master' branch

Scenario 2:

- I have 'master' & 'feature-1' branches in both local and remote repositories
- I make few commits in local 'feature-1' branch
- I push those changes to remote 'feature-1' branch
- Merge 'feature-1' with 'master' on remote server (GitHub)

Both ways work. So under what circumstances is each approach used?

Comment: Typically, teams go for the second approach to have a chance to review changes before they're merged. But both routes achieve the same thing, eventually.

Answer (score 4):

Just to clarify:

The question is tagged as `git`. On those terms, scenario 2 *does not exist*. Git will absolutely refuse to perform a merge at the server side. It has no provision for such a thing; indeed, it is forbidden. That is why you cannot push to a branch that has commits you don't have locally.

However, some Git hosting sites, such as GitHub, have created a mechanism termed a "pull request" or "merge request" where it *looks* like a merge is being performed on the server side. This mechanism involves not only the final merge but the display (via a web browser) of the diff and the ability to comment upon it before the merge. This is to permit multiple collaborators to review one another's work on a branch before a merge takes place. Many workplaces install rules at GitHub saying that pushing a local merge commit to the main branch is forbidden; the merge *must* be performed by way of a pull/merge request, and the merge will be forbidden until the branch has been explicitly *approved* by a collaborator.

So the rule is simple:

- If you are working alone, merge locally.
- If you share this repo with other collaborators who will be wanting, independently, to create branches to be merged into the main branch, then by all means take advantage of pull/merge requests on the server side to facilitate collaboration, and configure rules to enforce whatever your policies are.

Comment: I think the last sentence is key here: "...configure rules to enforce whatever your policies are." In shared repos, allowing anyone to be able to force push `master` is usually problematic, unless all users of the repo have a high level of Git knowledge.

Answer (score 3):

The end result is effectively the same, however if you have to abide by a review process, you'll want to to push your feature branch and then create pull or merge request and then have it merged remotely after it was reviewed and approved.

Comment: Can't we let the review happen in first scenario though? Before that commit is added to the remote 'master' branch?

Comment: @rakeshmehra How would a local merge be reviewed? Would everyone come to the merger's house and say, "Okay, go ahead and push"?

Comment: After we push the changes to remote "master" branch, does GitHub allow someone to review the changes, before actually creating that commit object in GitHub?

Comment: No, you shouldn't push it to the remote master branch, but to the remote feature-1 branch. Then, you can ask for reviews of it on that branch and once your changes are approved you can merge them into the master branch. Often you will use a tool like gitlab to manage that process, or the maintainer will perform the merge, because you may not have permission to merge directly onto master. Of course, you might also be allowed to merge locally and then push into master after approval, but that is "unprofessional".

Comment: You may want to read up on git essentials and branching models like gitflow: https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow
But the essence is: only work in branches and then have review confirm your changes and then have it merged into master.

Answer (score 0):

Simply **scenario 2**, because more colleagues get a chance to review it if needed, also to run any needed pipelines on push etc.